# Azure policy - restrict Public IP for VM

Tags: azure, azure-networking

It is possible to create an Azure policy to block the creation of a public IP if the VM already has an internal company IP??

Because we had a serious security issue

Any ideas to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a policy to block the creation of public Ip's and you can have that only apply to certain virtual networks. [This](https://blog.nillsf.com/index.php/2019/11/02/using-azure-policy-to-deny-public-ips-on-specific-vnets/) is a good article on how to do this.

Comment: love youuuuuuu!